# How to install a specific version of the Salesforce CLI on Linux?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, versioning, docker

I know that there is some code on how to install latect linux sfdx tar.xz archive inside container. you have to download the archive, unpack it and then run `./sfdx/install` which works fine. However, when I grap some speficic version of sfdx then there is **no installation script inside** in that archive, making `./sfdx/install` chunk of script unusable. how can I install it then? Thank you.
I am using ubuntu container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it using the node package manager (NPM):

```
$ npm install sfdx-cli@0.0.0 --global
```

Replacing `0.0.0` with the desired version number.

Comment: to be honest, I dont want to install additional sw into container... how can I install it from the package like the latest one? Thank you...

Comment: According to the documentation versions remain on the list for 20 weeks, and there is a manifest file with the list of versions. Have you searched for this at all? See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_olderversions

Comment: I have randomly checked 4 or 5 archives for linux x64 and all of them are missing the install script...

Comment: it seems that using npm was the only options for me...